# How to change primary key of a postgres database table from bill no to bill no and year part of purchase date column(it is oif type date)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table called `product_details` in my PostgreSQL database, two columns of this table are `bill_no INT` and `purchase_date DATE`.

Currently `bill_no` is the primary key, but my client wants it changed to `bill_no` and year of purchase, as bill numbers start with 1 at the start of every year.

Is there a way to change the primary key of the table to `bill_no` and only the **year part** of `purchase_date`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/bddc86150911120400w720a667bsb78bda73d1d598f1@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can drop a primary key like:

```
alter table bill drop constraint bill_pkey;
```

If the key's name is not "bill_pkey", use `\d` to find its name.

You can add a new primary key like:

```
alter table bill add constraint bill_pkey primary key (bill_no, purchase_date);
```

But you only want a key on the year part.  Postgres does not support that, but you can use a unique index:

```
create unique index ux_bill on bill (bill_no, extract(year from purchase_date));
```

A unique index will do everything a primary key does, but it won't have the primary key label.